# Android Loop Images

Tags: java, android

How do i loop this array, so that I do not have to write out 100 lines of images. I know it's simmple

```
private String[] pics = {
//want to loop these
        Constants.BASE_URL+"/bg/a/A1.jpg",
        Constants.BASE_URL+"/bg/a/A2.jpg",
        Constants.BASE_URL+"/bg/a/A3.jpg",
        Constants.BASE_URL+"/bg/a/A4.jpg",
        Constants.BASE_URL+"/bg/a/A5.jpg",
        Constants.BASE_URL+"/bg/a/A6.jpg",
 //
        };
```

Comment: for(int i =0;i<pics.length();i++){ // get the value.. pics[i]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using array then

```
String[] pics = new String[6];

// Fill it like this
for(int i=0; i<pics.length; i++) {
  pics[i] = Constants.BASE_URL+"/bg/a/A" + (i+1) + ".jpg";
}

// To traverse it
for(String picName : pics) {
   // picName contains the name
}
```

I hope this what you looking for.